# Фильтрация данных

Tags: sql, delphi, база-данных

Помогите разобраться с фильтрацией данных. Использую базу данных аксесс, компоненты ADOConnection, ADOQuery, ADODataSource, DBGrid, пара DateTimePicker и одна BitBtn
задаю запрос в SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Архив
WHERE Дата_выписки>= :first_date AND <= :last_date
```

Не идет хоть тресни. Что не так делаю, помогите.
UPD: Я в обработке кнопки пишу:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var  Date1,Date2:string;
 begin
  Date1:= DateTimePicker1.DateTime;
  Date2:= DateTimePicker2.DateTime;
  Form1.ADOQuery1.Active:= False;
  Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT *FROM Архив');
  Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE Дата_выписки');
  Form1.ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('BETWEEN ('+Date1+') AND ('+Date2+')');
  Form1.ADOQuery1.Active:= True;    
 end;    
end;
```

Не идет. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

1. Исправьте ошибку: WHERE Дата_выписки>= :first_date AND **Дата_выписки**<= :last_date
2. Так еще проще: WHERE Дата_выписки between :first_date and :last_date

Answer (score 0):

Сталкивался))) Скорее всего проблема в несовпадении форматов даты-времени
Передайте дату в виде параметра
У Вас же в исходном запросе в виде параметра и задается..
:first_date - это синтаксис параметра вот и передайте в запрос параметр, а Аксесс с делфи о форматах сами договорятся)))